# How to get all messages posted to slack for a day?

Tags: slack

I would like to (via the API) extract all messages for a day, posted to all (public) slack channels.

There seems to be two ways:

1. Use the channels.list + channels.history APIs, iterate over all channels and get the history. Seems super slow and the API seems flaky.
2. Use the search.messages API and use a "on:" query. Works, but the result is limited to 100*100 messages (100 items per page, 100 pages).

Do anyone know of any other smart way of going about extract all messages?

(I do not care about bots.)